# Query not excluding right amount of records using in clause

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to find excluded records from one table from another.

```
select old_fy.* 
from old_fy 
where "old_count_or_not" = "Count Current" or "old_count_or_not" = "Count Partial"
```

Returns 557 rows

```
select "My PK" from new_fy where "Count or not" = "Count Current" or "Count or not" = "Count Partial"
```

Returns 415 rows

Now, I want to do 557-415, thus I'm trying to run the following query:

```
select old_fy.* 
from old_fy 
where (old_fy."old_count_or_not" = "Count Current" or old_fy."old_count_or_not" = "Count Partial") 
and (old_fy."My PK" not in (select "My PK" from new_fy where "Count or not" = "Count Current" or "Count or not" = "Count Partial"));
```

It returns 234 when it should return 142 (557-415). Assuming something is slightly wrong with my syntax somehow.

Comment: Is there a difference when you remove the `"My PK" in` indirection?

Comment: If I remove the last and statement with the sub select, I'm essentially left with my first statement above, which returns 557. Unless this wasn't you meant.

Comment: `... where (...=... or ...=...) and (...=... or ...=...)`